# docker-compose mount single file with directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can't mount a file if I put it in a subdirectory (myconfig) relative to the docker-compose up command.
$PWD is /home/username/temp/ and docker-compose up run from there.

This is not working:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/myconfig/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

But this works if I copy nginx.conf to the $PWD directory:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

So none of these works:

```
$PWD/myconfig/nginx.conf
./myconfig/nginx.conf
/home/username/temp/myconfig/nginx.conf
```

But these work, if I copy $PWD/myconfig/nginx.conf to $PWD/config.conf:

```
./nginx.conf 
$PWD/nginx.conf
```

log:

```
Creating network "temp_default" with the default driver
Creating proxy ... error

ERROR: for proxy  Cannot create container for service proxy: not a directory

ERROR: for proxy  Cannot create container for service proxy: not a directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

However when I use the long syntax, it is working with subdirectory:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: $PWD/myconfig/nginx.conf
      target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Is here something that I miss, or is this a bug or lack of documentation?

Docker and docker-compose version:

```
➜  ~ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.7
 Version:           20.10.2
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        2291f61
 Built:             Mon Dec 28 16:17:34 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.2
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       8891c58
  Built:            Mon Dec 28 16:15:28 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
➜  ~ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192
docker-py version: 4.3.1
CPython version: 3.7.7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works fine for me.

```
# docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown
```

Since you mentioned that even with explicit path it was not working, while it was working inside your main folder, I would suggest to check the permissions for the `myconfig` folder. Make sure all users are allowed access and read ('x' and 'r')

```
# ls -ltr
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 23 06:03 myconfig
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  182 Feb 23 06:05 docker-compose.yml
```

if the the permissions are not correct, set them with `chmod a+xr myconfig/` and `chmod a+r myconfig/nginx.conf`

Comment: It is working now for me and I can't reproduce the error anymore neither can I check the permissions because I already deleted the folders. So we will never know what was the real problem for me, anyways your answer can be still helpful for others so I accepted it.

Comment: In my case the issue was exactly that, the usual, file permissions. The mounted file or parent dir must already exist with correct owner or permissions, otherwise directory is created by root, which is not writable by docker container.